# LibGDX - Missing LabelStyle font error

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

I have a folder named UI and inside it, it contains a button.pack and a button.png (I created this with the GDX texture packer). Here is the line of code for the .pack.

```
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/button.pack"));
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
```

But when I run the application it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing LabelStyle font.
```

Am I doing something wrong? What is the excact problem?

Comment: At which line is this Exception thrown?

Comment: what do you mean by "thrown"?

Comment: When a program errors, the error is "thrown"
Ex.
if (!everythingokay)
  throw new Exception("Error!");

Hense try/catch syntax:
try {
  /*This is risky bro!*/
}
catch(Exception e){/* Well.. That plan failed... */}

So, the dude was asking which of the two lines was erroring.